# How do you determine the variant for a recursive function in SML?

Tags: sml, variant

I'm having some trouble understanding what variants is in SML and how you determine the variant for a recursive function. I got the explanation:

"A variant for a (recursive) function is any expression over the function's arguments that takes values in some set A such that

- A is (totally) ordered; moreover, there are no infinite descending chains v0 > v1 > ... in A; and
- for any recursive call, the variant decreases strictly."

But that didn't really help me that much. A more specific example would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your recursive function makes a list of length `n`, in which all elements are zero.

This might look something like this:

```
fun foo 0 = []
  | foo n = 0::(foo (n - 1))
```

In this case, the variant is the argument `n` to the function.
`n` is a natural number, and the natural numbers are totally ordered with no infinite descending chains, as no chain can go below zero.
Further, `n` decreases strictly with each recursive call.

Another example: Suppose your function takes in two arguments, `x` and `y`, and returns true if `x > y` and false otherwise.

```
fun bar 0 y = false
  | bar x 0 = true
  | bar x y = bar (x - 1) (y - 1)
```

In this case, there are several options for the variant. You could take it to be either `x` or `y`, as in the previous example, or to be `x + y`. In any of these cases, it takes on natural number values and strictly decreases.

Now, for an example where the arguments are nonintegers -- finding the sum of a list.

```
fun sum [] = 0
  | sum (x::xs) = x + (sum xs)
```

In this case, the variant could be taken to be the length of the list (again a natural number), or to be the list itself, where lists are ordered as follows:

`l1 < l2` iff there is some finite sequence of elements `x1,x2,...,xn` such that
`x1::x2::...::xn::l1 = l2`.

It is fairly easy to show that the set of lists is partially ordered, with no infinite descending chains, under this comparison, and, in particular, the set of lists generated by recursive calls starting from some list is totally ordered.

Further, in any recursive call, `xs < (x::xs)`, by definition, so the list is decreasing.

The point of a variant is that it is a quantity that can be inducted over to prove things about the behaviour of a function. Since there are no infinite decreasing chains, there must be a minimum element, which can be taken as a base case for induction, and the total order then gives a way of inducting, from one element to the one immediately larger than it.

This can also be done with a partial order with no infinite decreasing chains, which guarantees that there are minimal elements, if not necessarily minimum elements. These can then be used as base cases, and a similar induction argument made, though likely with multiple ways of constructing larger elements.